# CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'LocalScale'

Tags: c#, game-development

I'm learning to do some game development and I'm new to the C family in general, so I can't figure out what its asking for. Thank you for everyone's help! I also tried researching this before posting, but I couldn't find any solutions.

Here is the error:
Assets\Scripts\Player.cs(12,21): error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'LocalScale' and no accessible extension method 'LocalScale' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    Transform GFX;
    float flipX;

      void Start() {
        GFX = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().transform;
        flipX = GFX.LocalScale.x;
    }

    void Update() {
        float horz = System.Math.Sign(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        if(Mathf.Abs(horz) > 0)
        {
            GFX.LocalScale = new Vector2(flipX * horz, GFX.LocalScale.y);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I tried to use brackticks for code and it came out odd, it wouldn't encase the code. So I omitted them. Sorry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html

It's just a casing error. It's `localScale` and not `LocalScale`

Comment: THANK YOU! Ill accept the answer as soon as I can. In the video I'm watching, the guy's font changes depending on how its used in his scripting console and it throws me off a lot. It changes to like italics, so it looked like an uppercase L. Thanks a bunch that fixed it!

Comment: I am glad I could help. If you are just starting out, I would advise you to always check unity's documentation if some function or built-in variable is not working correctly.